# Maximal performance animal, cannon glass animal

Tags: creature-design

why walk from point A to point B? Run so fast your tendoms rupture.

A predator attacks you? Punch it so hard your own fist shatters then stab it in the eye with your own broken bones.

Gotta find a tactical solution to a really problematic situation? Think so hard you make chess masters envious and collapse from the mental stress once the problem is solved.

I want an animal that hybernates a lot and eats like a mofo to recover and prepare, but the few moments it is awaken it performs like a god in anything.

I know children can be born with such an arithmetic capacity to defeat grown adults in intelligence based games like Samuel Reshevsky for example.

I know children can grow really fast, specially whales can put on 90 kilograms of mass in a day, so fast regeneration is perfectly possible, repairing something is even easier than building it for the first time.

I know from personal experience that different hormones can make animals immune to pain and fear.

So what stops an animal that sleeps something like a few weeks in a row and when it wakes it can wreck havoc from evolving?

It goes like this:

Wake up > run till you find food, eat all of it and kill everything in your way, also eat it > find a hiding spot > sleep to regenerate your broken bones from all the fighting and running and also to digest the 7 people you ate on your way back.

specific problem = a creature that doesn't care about getting hurt at all, smart enough to solve most problems and with high energy demands thus the long rests.

Comment: Many animals *are* evolved for short bursts of high intensity activity. Cheetahs, for example, spend almost 90% of their time doing absolutely nothing, and a fraction of their time running faster than any other animal on the planet to chase down and kill large prey. That doesn't mean a cheetah can run twice as fast if it rests twice as long, though.

Comment: Welcome to the Worldbuilding Stack Exchange! Currently your question is a little sprawled, which makes it harder for people to answer. I'd like to suggest you keep rhetorical questions to a minimum and focus on the following structure: Start with the conditions of your world (e.g. "I have a creature that has to run really quickly...") then ask the single question you want answered (e.g. "How can they do this?" or "Does this make sense?"). If you already have an idea for an answer you can write a separate answer.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Related: [a bear once ate 70 pounds of cocaine in one meal, making it the most dangerous predator ever in history](https://www.iflscience.com/plants-and-animals/cocaine-bear-the-true-story-of-a-bear-that-ate-70-pounds-of-cocaine/) - if only for a short while. It would meet your requirements if it had survived and healed.

Comment: What stops? Hibernation must be safe. An animal should retire for the rest on a full stomach and be ready to destroy anyone who dares to disturb its sleep. So if this animal does not have has some kind of safe lair with stored food, its regeneration and recreation is problematic.

Comment: There seem to be two different questions here. One is that you want such a creature, the next is why it wouldn't evolve. I'm voting to close until this is clarified.

Comment: "So what stops an animal that sleeps something like a few weeks in a row and when it wakes it can wreck (sic) havoc from evolving?"  Contrary to mislabeled "science" fiction, individuals do not evolve.  Ever.  Populations evolve over many generations due to accumulation of favourable mutations.  Which means that the question needs to be clarified, both in terminology and to answer the other questions raised in comments.

Answer (score 2):

## This creature doesn't evolve because there are more efficient ways to do things

Ok, firstly, a creature won't be good at *everything*. Creatures only evolve things that are helpful to survival/reproduction, and being able to recite Harry Potter in alphabetical order isn't helpful. And your creature won't just evolve "general intelligence" since that's not really a thing. Intelligence isn't some monolithic skill, it's thousands of individual ones. For example, you might consider humans to be "generally intelligent" but it turns out humans are really bad at really simple things, like remembering things, which is trivial for a computer, and good at really hard things, like translating between languages, or walking, which is hard for computers (for now). This is because we evolved the aspects of intelligence that were useful to us, which included language, but did not include remembering millions of numbers. This applies to other traits as well, as creatures will only evolve traits that help with survival or reproduction (in general).

But even if we cut the general intelligence, and stick to mostly strength, the population will evolve to be less self destructive. I mean, first, you have to go weeks without food, which some animals can do by lowering metabolism, but your creatures cannot since they have to heal. Healing is super energy intensive, as you need to move all kinds of chemicals around, make new cells, discard old cells, an much more. Inactive patients (according to this https://www.hss.edu/conditions_nutrition-for-healing.asp) after surgery 15-20 calories per kilogram, which is about the same amount as a normal, active person. Remember that your animal should be trying to reduce metabolism as low as possible, as it will be going weeks without food. Furthermore, there is no guarantee that the healing will be successful, which could leave permanent damage.

Now imagine if one of your creatures gets a mutation that reactivates it's pain receptors when awake. Sure, it no longer able to get massive amounts of food, but it also needs a lot less energy, since when sleeping it is no longer healing. This creature will probably be able to survive longer than the hyper-aggressive creatures, since it is not regularly breaking bones and tearing tendons, nor is it at risk of starving to death. Of course, it could turn out that your predator needs to break bones to be able to take down prey. However, if that's the case, your herbivores probably also break bones running away from the predators, meaning they need time to heal, which makes them vulnerable to attack. Overall, there reason your creature doesn't evolve is because it's not super efficient to risk death and starvation every month when you can just not and live longer

Answer (score 0):

Rolling giant neural-networking "amoeba", coiled into a muscular ball.
In fact, a total brain, and at the same time cells of neurons work this way and that (as muscular cells),this amoeba fall on the victims, crushes them and digests them with cellular digestion ...
Wounds are insignificant - considering all this neural network structure as well as regeneration ...

Comment: and why didn't it evolve? in the real world I mean

Comment: ''So what stops an animal that sleeps something like a few weeks in a row and when it wakes it can wreck havoc from evolving?''

Comment: "evolve" in what ?

Comment: evolve into existance

Comment: 5%, "wreck havoc from evolving?" "evolve into existance" -  Sorry, i don't understand these phrases and concept; what is it mean, in other words ?

Comment: @sleeves for the same reason anything else didn't evolve into the real world: evolutionary pressure

Comment: Juliana Karasava Sousa, in real evolution, a different variety of types of animals were encountered; however, of course, the evolutionary ecological "balance" has not yet been turned off. (exclude humans, of course :>)

Answer (score 0):

In evolution, everything is "trying" to be as optimized as possible. So much so that you usually can figure out the traits of a predator from the traits of the prey and vice versa.

> I want an animal that hibernates a lot and eats like a mofo to recover and prepare, but the few moments it is awaken it performs like a god in anything.

The prey that this animal is optimized for would be fast, smart, and large. Large enough to provide enough sustenance. Fast enough to be able to put up a challenge. And smart enough that the prey would recognize an animal of this kind while it is recovering.

Since prey always outnumber predator, they could kill this predator in its hibernation, making them extinct. If the prey were less capable, then the predator would be similarly less capable. Any extra capability in a predator is either too heavy or inefficient and therefore too costly in the amount of food it would need.

> I know children can grow really fast, specially whales can put on 90 kilograms of mass in a day, so fast regeneration is perfectly possible, repairing something is even easier than building it for the first time.

Repairing would cost less material, yes, but it needs to be done way more carefully. You essentially trade material cost for time. This means that you are vulnerable for much longer, and likely to die due to an infection, or from another animal, probably the smart prey you hunt. Unless you stay awake. But then, you are under way more time pressure.

In short, infection would kill you if you get to many injuries each time you hunt. And you won't be able to hibernate, since the prey you hunt is smart enough to kill you in your sleep.